# angular doesn't select selectbox option from complex object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a trouble selecting option when Object comes from server.

```
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-hide="trip.checked1"
            ng-model="trip.location"
            ng-change="tripLocationChange(shift, trip)"
            ng-options="obj as obj.text for obj in locations" required>
   </select>
```

my incoming object is

```
"location":{"text":"Foo","value":"f6a62517"}
```

and I populate selectBox with

```
$scope.locations = [{"text":"Bar","value":"f07a2bc4"},{"text":"Foo","value":"f6a62517"}]
```

I believe the problem lies in here
`ng-options="obj as obj.text for obj in locations"`

any thoughts will be appreciated

Comment: Show how you set `$scope.trip.location`?

Comment: I took this from bigger context `  <tr ng-repeat="trip in shift.trips">` there is a repeat on shifts as well. but basically I am able to get ` <h4 ng-show="trip.checked1">{{trip.location.text}}</h4>` with no problems

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that even though the object that comes from server which you set as `$scope.trip.location` looks similar to the one in `$scope.locations` array, they are **different** objects. At the same time, Angular checks for object equility in order to set selectbox option as selected, and two object are equal only if the are the **same** object. This is not your case.

In your case you will have to loop though `$scope.locations` array, find proper object and set `$scope.trip` to found value. This should work for you:

```
// trip object came from server
var trip = {"location":{"text":"Foo","value":"f6a62517"}};

// use it to find similar object in $scope.locations array
$scope.trip = {
    location: $scope.locations.filter(function(location) {
        return location.value === trip.location.value;
    })[0]
};
```

Comment: **thank you** for showing me the way, got it working like this
`trips[y].location = $scope.locations.filter(function (location) {
                        return location.value === trips[y].location.value;
                    })[0]`